# In T SQL, how can I query and unpivot the contents of an XML tag?

Tags: sql, xml, nodes

Is it possible to query `OUTER APPLY nodes(ChildTag1 OR ChildTag2)` as my current query, using `nodes(ChildTag1) OUTER APPLY nodes(ChildTag2)` produces an incorrect cross-joined output:

Current Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT 'Sample Text 1' AS ID,
              CONVERT(XML, '<Root>
                              <ParentTag ParentTagID="Sample Text 2">
                                <ChildTag1>5</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag1>6</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag2>7</ChildTag2>
                                <ChildTag2>8</ChildTag2>
                              </ParentTag>
                            </Root>'
                      ) AS SampleXML
)
SELECT ID,
       Root.ParentTag.value('@ParentTagID','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ParentTagID,
       RootParentTag1.ChildTag1.value('(text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ChildTag1,
       RootParentTag2.ChildTag2.value('(text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ChildTag2
FROM CTE
OUTER APPLY CTE.SampleXML.nodes('/Root/ParentTag') as Root(ParentTag)
OUTER APPLY Root.ParentTag.nodes('ChildTag1') as RootParentTag1(ChildTag1)
OUTER APPLY Root.ParentTag.nodes('ChildTag2') as RootParentTag2(ChildTag2)
```

Current Output:

```
ChildTag1 ChildTag2
5         7
5         8
6         7
6         8
```

This reworked query using union and two separate sections of querying XML produces the correct output but is this the most efficient method or is there an easier and cleaner way?

Reworked Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT 'Sample Text 1' AS ID,
              CONVERT(XML, '<Root>
                              <ParentTag ParentTagID="Sample Text 2">
                                <ChildTag1>5</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag1>6</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag1>7</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag2>8</ChildTag2>
                                <ChildTag2>9</ChildTag2>
                                <ChildTag2>10</ChildTag2>
                              </ParentTag>
                            </Root>'
                      ) AS SampleXML
)
SELECT ID,
       Root.ParentTag.value('@ParentTagID','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ParentTagID,
       RootParentTag1.ChildTag1.value('(text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ChildTag1,
       NULL
FROM CTE
OUTER APPLY CTE.SampleXML.nodes('/Root/ParentTag') as Root(ParentTag)
OUTER APPLY Root.ParentTag.nodes('ChildTag1') as RootParentTag1(ChildTag1)
UNION
SELECT ID,
       Root.ParentTag.value('@ParentTagID','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ParentTagID,
       NULL,
       RootParentTag2.ChildTag2.value('(text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ChildTag2
FROM CTE
OUTER APPLY CTE.SampleXML.nodes('/Root/ParentTag') as Root(ParentTag)
OUTER APPLY Root.ParentTag.nodes('ChildTag2') as RootParentTag2(ChildTag2)
```

Reworked Output:

```
ChildTag1 ChildTag2
5         NULL
6         NULL
NULL         7
NULL         8
```

Comment: Please include the query you now have in the question.

Comment: Hi @TT. I've added the current query

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit shorter, still relying on UNION ALL (since no duplicates are possible in your example XML). I see no problems in terms of performance here.

```sql
;WITH CTE AS
( SELECT 'Sample Text 1' AS ID,
              CONVERT(XML, '<Root>
                              <ParentTag ParentTagID="Sample Text 2">
                                <ChildTag1>5</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag1>6</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag1>7</ChildTag1>
                                <ChildTag2>8</ChildTag2>
                                <ChildTag2>9</ChildTag2>
                                <ChildTag2>10</ChildTag2>
                              </ParentTag>
                            </Root>'
                      ) AS SampleXML
)
SELECT
    n.v.value('.','INT') AS ChildTag1,
    NULL AS ChildTag2
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY SampleXML.nodes('/Root/ParentTag/ChildTag1/text()') as n(v)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL AS ChildTag1,
    n.v.value('.','INT') AS ChildTag2
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY SampleXML.nodes('/Root/ParentTag/ChildTag2/text()') as n(v)
```